# Is it possible to hide the keyboard with a button?

Tags: java, android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard, android-tabhost

In my app, I have a Tab system, and in one of the tab layouts, there is an EditText.

[image]

And if I go to a different tab, the keyboard stays up.

[image]

So I've added a button that would hide it:

[image]

So how do I set the Button to closing the keyboard? It would also be very helpful if the keyboard went away when switching tabs.

Comment: There are a lot of answers here about this topic.

Comment: Maybe so, but not about my specific situation with the tabs and using a seperate button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void hideKeyboard() {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getTabHost().getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

This method hides the keyboard. Works in tab case. Just set on the each tab the same OnClickListener, which calls hideKeyboard().

Comment: I used it inside of an OnTabChangeListener and it worked great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What i've done in my app is try and not use a button to close the softkeyboard cause i'm already using a button, instead of your Done, called Del whcih empties out the EditText field. What i've done is on the first press of the EditText show the keyboard, and at a second press just hide it.

**Try using this in the onClick callback function for the EditText, OR if you want to keep the   Submit button, then add this on it's onClick listener and for every tab you have as well.**

```
InputMethodManager keyboard = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
keyboard.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Hope this helps, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
```

add these to the event when you want to hide soft keyboard...